# Getting package information about a Windows 8 application

Tags: windows, deployment

I realize that a Windows 8 application is contained within a Windows 8 Package.
Is there a programmatic way to get the PackageId, the installed location and any external dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can leverage the Windows Runtime Packaging API.

To start, you can retrieve some PackageVersion information.There is a package version number.

You can read about it here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.packageversion.aspx

There are various objects that give you additional information.

```
Package package = Package.Current;
PackageId packageId = package.Id;
PackageVersion version = packageId.Version;
```

Here are some of the details available:

```
packageId.Name
version.Major
version.Minor
version.Build
version.Revision
packageId.Architecture
packageId.ResourceId
packageId.Publisher
packageId.PublisherId
packageId.FullName
packageId.FamilyName
package.IsFramework
```